# iphone UILabel-how to show tamil characters, is it posible to show tamil keyboard as well?

Tags: iphone

I am a newbie for iphone development, i wish to show some list of tamil words in a UILable. when i try, i am getting most of the characters looking somthing wrong. Is there any easy way to show the tamil characters looking exactly like its shape? is it posible to show tamil keyboard? is iphone sdk contain tamil keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the iPhone has no official support for Tamil. Its [specs](http://www.apple.com/iphone/specs.html) page on the Apple website doesn't mention it, in any case.

That said, Cocoa (and its sibling on iOS; Cocoa Touch) has well-rounded support for Unicode. [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) includes [Tamil code points](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0B80.pdf). If you wanted to use this code points in a UILabel, you would have limited selection in terms of fonts; Arial Unicode MS may be your only option.

As of iOS 3.2, `UITextView` has had the [`inputView` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/inputView), allowing you to present your own keyboard. Coupled with the [`UITextInput` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), you could conceivably create your own fully-featured Tamil keyboard.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable notes. I have found an option in sdk 4.1 , it has tamil fonts(even most of the indian language fonts like malayalam, telugu, etc.,)

Comment: font name :TamilSangamMN-Bold and TamilSangamMN,  the below code snipet will show the list of available font family and its font names. for (NSString *family in [UIFont familyNames])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", family);
        for (NSString *font in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:family])
        {
            NSLog(@"\t%@", font);
        }
    }