# Display Telugu Text using local HTML file and web view IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, fonts

Hi i want to view Telugu font in my iPhone i have used the local HTML file to display the Telugu font so i have copied the some Telugu font using Google translator but its not showing. But i have seen some solutions for the Tamil font in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443818/how-to-display-tamil-characters-into-uitextview-from-rtf-doc-file?lq=1)  in same is there any way to display Telugu font in the local HTML.

Its showing like this.

[image]

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Before display any custom font that is not supported in iPhone, you need to add this font to ios.

You need to add your Font to yourApp-Info.plist. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490696/using-custom-font-in-a-uiwebview) will help you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add custom fonts in your project before you use them.

This includes following steps:

1. Include your fonts in your XCode project
2. Make sure that they’re included in the target
3. Double check that your fonts are included as Resources in your bundle
4. Include your iOS custom fonts in your application plist
5. Find the name of the font
6. Use UIFont and specify the name of the font

Moreover refer to this answers on stackoverflow

[iOS-Custom Font setting with Fonts specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15984937/adding-custom-fonts-to-ios-app-finding-their-real-names)